# ArcGIS Pro 2.5 - Raster stretch - change minimum maximum values

Tags: raster, symbology, arcgis-pro

ArcGIS Pro 2.5 - When I set a raster to stretch symbology and use a minimum maximum for the value range, how/where do I change the minimum and maximum values?  In ArcMap there used to be a little tick box than would let you override the minimum and maximum, where has that functionality gone? (assuming it is even in ArcGIS 'Pro')

Answer (score 2):

A little workaround that might help:

In the symbology pane, go to the histogram editing. There, you can narrow your symbology boundaries manually (although it is annoying that you can't specify values accurately).

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that in there you can double click on the numbers on the boundaries and specify them accurately, so I think this might do the trick.